# Is there a "prettier" way to do this?

Tags: c#, foreach

Say I have the line

```
dirs.ToList().ForEach(d => item.Items.Add(MyMethod(d)));
```

But now I want to avoid adding to my list if the method returns null. Is there a prettier way than

```
foreach(var d in dirs)
{
    object obj = MyMethod(d);
    if(obj != null)
        myList.Items.Add(obj);
}
```

?

Comment: What type is `item.Items`? Is it something that has an `AddRange` method?

Comment: You can just do something like this; `dirs.ToList().ForEach(d => {var tmp = MyMethod(d); if(tmp != null) item.Add(tmp);});` However, I'd stick with a normal foreach loop - you're iterating the collection twice here (`.ToList()` and then the `.ForEach()`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Select()` to call `MyMethod()` and then filter the list using `Where()`:

```
var filteredDirs = dirs.Select(MyMethod)
                       .Where(d => d != null);
```

If `item.Items` supports `AddRange()` (or if you write it as an extension method for it), you can then do something like this:

```
item.Items.AddRange(filteredDirs);
```

If it doesn't support it (and you don't want to write an extension method fo it), `foreach` is probably best:

```
foreach (var dir in filteredDirs)
    item.Items.Add(dir);
```

But there is nothing wrong with simple imperative code like you posted, as others said.

Answer (score 10):

I fail to see what is wrong with a simple loop.  Honestly, I don't know why some people have an obsessive need to use LINQ or whatever shiny new tool/syntactical construct they have recently discovered when the simplest and most logical answer is right in front of them.

There is nothing wrong with your loop; worry about solving real problems.

Comment: I agree. This is a slightly disturbing trend to LINQ-ify every loop in C# these days :/ I'm guilty of it tbh.

Comment: It's good to know what the alternatives are though, so you can choose what you think is best.

Comment: I like to refer to LINQ as .NET's jQuery. That is all.

Comment: To be fair to the OP, he(?) never actually mentions linq, it's possible he's after a non-linq way (such as AddRange)

Comment: @RichK: Add range *would* be better, but his example does not allow for it.  He is calling a method `MyMethod` that returns a single object and then adding that object to a collection.

Answer (score 2):

If it were *my* code, this is likely how it would look:

```
foreach(var name in dirs         // dunno if "name" is correct :)
      .Select(d => MyMethod(d))  // or .Select(MyMethod), depending
      .Where(n => n != null)) {
    myList.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Of, if AddRange is supported:

```
myList.Items.AddRange(
  dirs.Select(d => MyMethod(d))
      .Where(n => n != null));
```

*However*, I find nothing terrible about the `foreach` case posted and, in fact: **`foreach { if ... }` is *very desirable* in cases.**

This is because it can be *trivially expanded* to `foreach { if ... else ... }`. C# 3.0/4.0 doesn't have a terribly friendly way of dealing with partitioned lists and, in cases where the order is import, the approach of partitioning and *then* processing the lists separately is not a viable solution. In such cases, I still *generally* (but not always) use LINQ for as much of the transformation as possible:

```
foreach(var name in dirs
      .Select(d => MyMethod(d))) {
   if (name != null) {
     myList.Items.Add(name);
   } else {
     SingMerrySongsAndDanceAHappyLittleJig(); // or ... whatever
   }
}
```

I *do not* use `ForEach` for side-effects and I *avoid side effects in LINQ queries.* This includes exceptions! Much of my code that deals with LINQ actually returns `IList<T>` and not `IEnumerable<T>` to ensure it is "forced" in the appropriate context. Laziness if good, except when it isn't: C# is not Haskell.

Happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
dirs.Select(dir => MyMethod(dir))
    .Where(result => result != null)
    .ForEach(result => item.Items.Add(result));
```

would be how I would go about it.